# Decoding video frames and sending them to RabbitMQ using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rabbitmq

I've built **ffmpeg** with **AMQP** support and tried `ffmpeg -i /videos/episode.mp4 -f mpegts amqp://localhost` which apparently works. But AFAIK **mpegts** has some *muxing overhead*, so I don't really know how it splits stream into messages.

Is it possible to *decode* all the frames from a video and send them one-by-one in some format (say, **JPEG** or **PNG**) to **RabbitMQ**?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:
ffmpeg -i /videos/episode.mp4 -f mjpeg amqp://localhost